# How to call signalr client method from different server

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have javascript client code:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    var chat = $.connection.notificationHub;

    chat.client.newMessage = function (message) {
        alert(message);
        // Add the message to the page.
        $('#messages').append('<li><strong>' +  message + '</strong>: </li>');
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done();
});
</script>
```

My hub class in an dll name -- signalcomponent

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendAll(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.newMessage(message);
    }
}
```

my signalrcomponent is now used in another website(backend) from where i want to send message to another website, but using the same hub.

In backend website, i use signalrcomponent dll and samehub

now i try to call the "newMessage" method of other website/client

using following code:

```
public class NotificationBroadcaster
{
    private IHubContext _hubContext;

    public NotificationBroadcaster()
    {
        _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    }


    public async Task SendAll(string message)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.newMessage(message);
    }


}
```

But this is not working

help please

Comment: I would try the singleton design pattern

Comment: So shd i create NOtificationHub class as singleton ?

Comment: Yes, but thinking again, I would try one approach using messaging. I would create a service to dequeue messages and broadcast to clients of the hub. It will take a few more time, but I'll believe it will work. Maybe it won't fix your need because this time to enqueue / dequeue messages will degrade the real time experience.

Comment: i tried with singleton design pattern , but it didnot work